# Html.fromHtml keeps throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, html, string

Say I have a String that I have formatted to contain bold letters. But at some point I need to be able to strip the formatting. Below is what I have tried but keep getting NullPointerException

Here is my method

```
public String stripFormatting(String input){
    return Html.fromHtml(input).toString();
}
```

Here is a call

```
stripFormatting("<b>0</b>")
```

The error trace is not saying much, but here

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mypkg.utils.MyClassTest.stripFormatting(MyClassTest.java:111)
at com.mypkg.utils.MyClassTest.testLessThan100_000(MyClassTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Answer (score 5):

I see you're trying to run this from a unit test - calling `Html.fromHtml` *will not work as intended* because unit tests can't use Android dependent code.

According to Building Local Unit Tests https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html under *Mock Android Dependencies* -

> By default, the Android Plug-in for Gradle executes your local unit tests against a modified version of the android.jar library, which does not contain any actual code. Instead, method calls to Android classes from your unit test throw an exception. This is to make sure you test only your code and do not depend on any particular behavior of the Android platform (that you have not explicitly mocked).

It's easily fixed, though - just change your test from a unit test to an instrumentation test (ie, under the `androidTest` directory, which will actually use the full android.jar rather than a stub like for unit tests). It'll be a little slower to run but should at least execute correctly.

Certain things are mockable (eg, `getString` from `context`s via Mockito as described in the above link) but that doesn't work for static methods. I suspect if you're testing HTML stripping you'll want to actually test that it's doing what you expect, so an instrumentation test is the way to go.

Comment: I did as you suggested. From within android studio, I move the directory to be a child of `(androidTest)`. But now it keeps say: "Class not found ... Empty test suite".

Comment: You probably need to annotate the test class with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` above the class declaration (ie, above `public class ...Test {` to tell Android Studio it's an instrumentation test. You can find more information here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Comment: I am having no luck. And I have been looking at the official docs and all over stack overflow. It keeps saying "class not found: "mypackage.MyClass"Empty test suite`

Comment: For others who are facing same problem as @NouvelTravay every time you move your test from `test` to `androidTest` directory or vice-versa, goto `edit configuration` and delete any tests mentioned there, under configurations, and run your tests again. It will work.